# Code Signing for Linux

Tags: linux, cryptography, code-signing, digital-certificate, integrity

Are there any providers offering code signing certificates for (Red Hat Enterprise) Linux?  I see a lot of buzz for Microsoft-land, but not much for Linux.

I know how to generate my own certificates and embed a public certificate into my executable.  I'm specifically looking for ways to get the certificate signed by a trusted CA.  The target system is RHEL 5 Server.

An alternative question:
What root certificate authorities are trusted by RHEL 5 Server out of the box?

Comment: What would be the point? Do you have a loader that will check the signature prior to executing, or any other system to process the signature?

For your second question, I again ask another question: trusted for what? PKI enabled software components like browsers will have a list of trusted CAs, but what would the RH Linux use such a list for? Maybe for code-signing if it supported it...

Comment: That is my question basically: does RHEL support code signing.  Thanks for the confirmation Greg and Tim.

Comment: Strange, I did not know it's didn't support code signing.

Comment: Code signing at what level? Shell? Repository? Kernel? UEFI?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In all reality and practicality, most people just use self signed certs. RHEL customers trust entire *repositories* in addition to sums of individual packages. So yes, you could sign your executable, but beyond letting it trust itself it would do very little good on a stock RHEL system.

A list of trusted CAs can be found somewhere in /etc, I forget the exact location but it should be rather conspicuous.

Comment: That is the same conclusion I've come to.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A commercial code signing certificate does not specify what applications it can be used for.  So any code signing cert from a publicly trusted CA can be used.  With Linux you need to ensure that the relying party has access to the verification certificate.

The answer about trusting repositories may soon be outdated if it isn't already.  If Software Bills of Materials (SBOM) become standard it will be necessary for build tools to be able to verify digital signatures and self-signed certs will not be widely trusted.